# Whitelist IP for invisible reCaptcha v2

Tags: recaptcha

Our customer service is an important user of our website. When doing their work they frequently send requests to the part of our website that is protected by invisible reCaptcha (v2). For that reason I think their actions are being marked as suspicion by reCaptcha and they keep getting the reCaptcha where you need to select photo's with a certain image, this makes their work has become quite a bit more time consuming. Is their a solution for this? Perhaps by whitelisting our IP so traffic from our IP will never be suspicious, and the reCaptcha with the images will not show?

I couldn't find the answer in the documentation so hope that someone can help!